# Unable to display an image when another is displayed from the same directory

Tags: php, html, laravel, image

I have two pages `home.blade.php` and `post.blade.php` in the same directory i.e: `resources/views` directory. When I display the image in home page like:

```
<img src="storage\file_uploads\{{$item->id}}">
```

It runs sweet and display the image. But when I do the same thing in post page like:

```
<img src="storage\file_uploads\{{$post->id}}">
<!-- It is needed to mention that the $post and $item variable are not causing the problem for sure and the file does exist-->
```

I have run a php artisan command: `php artisan storage:link` to link the public and storage folder and everything was running sweet.
So, What may be the problem.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Why do you use backslashes in the web context?

Comment: It is already solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your URL changes according to your route, the path defined in the HTML tags will also change as they are relative.

To solve this issue use image tag like this:

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/file_uploads')}}/{{$post->id}}" >
```

**NOTE:** Other import tags for CSS and JS (style and script) are also to be imported the similar way. Like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('yourpath/css/style.css') }}">
<script src="{{ URL::asset('yourpath/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```